# Get indicator with trade entry value - Pine Script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to set stop loss of 2ATR at moment of trade entry. With Pine Script I set stop loss of 2ATR, however not at moment of trade entry, but Pine Script updates ATR value to last closed candle.Preferred verion is v4 are v5 of PS.

Thanks

```
atr = atr(14)

if EntryShortCondiction1 and EntryShortCondiction2
    strategy.entry("Short", false, 100)
    
ShortStop = (strategy.position_avg_price + atr*2)
ShortProfit = (strategy.position_avg_price - atr*2)

if strategy.position_size<0
    strategy.exit(id = "Short", stop=ShortStop, limit=ShortProfit)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `strategy.opentrades.entry_price` variable to get the entry price.

Here is an example:

```
//@version=5
strategy("My strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

_atr = ta.atr(14)

longCondition = ta.crossover(ta.sma(close, 14), ta.sma(close, 28))

if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

lastEntryPrice = strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1)

var float tp = na
var float sl = na

if (strategy.position_size[1] != strategy.position_size)
    tp := lastEntryPrice + (_atr * 2)
    sl := lastEntryPrice - (_atr * 2)

inTrade = strategy.position_size > 0

plot(inTrade ? tp : na, color=color.green, style=plot.style_circles)
plot(inTrade ? sl : na, color=color.red, style=plot.style_circles)
plot(lastEntryPrice)

strategy.exit("Short", "Long", stop=sl, limit=tp)
```

[image]

So, entry price is 55334,19, atr at that moment is 2725,88. Take profit = 55334,19 + (2 * 2725,88) = 60785,95 which seems to be correct.

Comment: Do you know how to fix this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70932130/all-pyramiding-trades-close-at-the-same-time