# Indicator value for specific bar index

Tags: pine-script

I have specific bar index from the beginning of the chart (ex. 6500). How can I get atr value for this bar?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use an if condition and store the value if the bar_index is 6500.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")
_atr = ta.atr(14)

var float atr6500 = na

if (bar_index == 6500)
    atr6500 := _atr

plot(_atr)
plot(atr6500, color=color.green)
plot(bar_index, color=color.yellow)
```

[image]

Comment: I said 6500 only as an example. Will it work on strategy instead of study?

Comment: The same problem shown another way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70874632/get-indicator-with-trade-entry-value-pine-script

Comment: Yes it will work whether it's a strategy or indicator.