# How to set closing price based on last swing high prior to entry?

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to set a close/exit price to be equal to or greater than the last swing high prior to my entry (by "swing high" I mean upFractal in this case).

Also, it must work with pyramiding, just to complicate matters.

Please see this example - I colour-coded each entry with its related previous swing high. upFractal, and its exit:

[image]

I currently don't understand how to reference that swing high that is prior to each entry, or how to keep them distinct/unique to each entry as shown in the screen shot. I believe it possibly involves referencing the open trade number.

My maximum number of open trades (pyramiding) is likely going to be 5, which may be helpful to know.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for clarifying your question, in `strategy`, set    `process_orders_on_close` to `true`

```
strategy("StackOverFlow", overlay=true, process_orders_on_close=true)`
```

Comment: Hi Mazen, thanks for your answer. So in my case the buy condition may be true some time after my bar, not like an MA cross. Or you can even imagine a situation where an MA cross happens again after the entry, and  `sma_long` would update, undesirably. We really only want to target the MA cross that happened prior to the entry. Therefore this solution wouldn't work, and is the thrust of my question. It must be the upFractal that happened prior to my actual entry that is targeted. Perhaps you can update accordingly, thanks again.

Comment: The answer has been modified

Comment: Thanks Mazen! But I don't understand how this current answer has anything to do with the question? Perhaps you can illuminate and/or add some context insofar as how this relates. Thanks again.

Comment: with `process_orders_on_close` the condition will be work when MA crosses! not after closing. also,  check out this answer I hope to help you
[Get indicator with trade entry value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70874632/get-indicator-with-trade-entry-value-pine-script)

Comment: Thanks again. So I do think you're missing my point - and I understand that sometimes just describing these things in few words can be challenging. My point is that it must the the condition that was most recently before the entry (i.e., the last fractal), and not after the entry. I have a verbose solution that I coded today that I will post as an answer to better show the question and how I am currently solving it. Thanks again.